# Determining Vo in a diode circuit using iterative analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, transient, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEp56s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Say  we have this circuit. Then we were asked to find Vo using iterative analysis. We were told to stop when the estimate is accurate to within 15mV. I just want to confirm my understanding of the question.

- Is the 15mV the Vo that we should be aiming to get?
- And so,  if it is, we should be looking for the values of Id or Vd, right?
- What will be the right approach here? Could I first assume Vd to be 1/2Vout (Since I could find Id when I know Vd) and then just adjust it till I get to 15mV?

My KVL equation is: (Id is based from the exponential model of the diode)
$$ Vout = V1 - iD(R1) - 2Vd $$

The following are given:
Is (reverse sat. current) = 1fA
Ideality factor = 1
Operating temp = 27 C

Comment: Take a look at this and then share your approach with us? The question is asking you to calculate Vout +/- 15mV, 15mV is NOT the answer. You haven't stated what the diode model (I assume it's been provided) is so the information in the question is incomplete.

Comment: The diode model has not been stated explicitly. But since saturation current, ideality factor and operating  temp is given, I think its natural to assume that its the exponential model?

Comment: Great. So since your working are going to rely upon that formula you'll need to show it here...I don't see an operating temp or saturation current provided either.

Comment: Vout will be 1V theoretically, but not in real life. The diodes require 0.5V to 0.7V in order to be on, if they are on, they will maintain the voltage at their own voltage, if they are not on, then the voltage will equal the source, which is 1 V. Diodes start conducting at 0.3V approximately, so some current will flow even then. The resistor will limit the current. You have to know what will the voltage be over the diodes, for a specific current. They must be described in the datasheet.

Comment: @mhaselup Ill edit the question! Thank you!

Comment: @CFCBazarcom The type of diode is not given. I guess that's why they want us to use trial and error.

Comment: The type of diode is only necessary for accurate calculations, all diodes are withing the border 0.5V, 0.7V to be fully on and they start conducting at less than 0.5V. Here the trick would be what is the technology of the diode. Is it a silicon diode, which requires 0.5V, schottky diode at 0.2V, germanium diode at 0.25V-0.30V or a different diode. However I don't think they will pressure you this much, so you can except a general silicone diode which starts conducting at 0.3V, in which case you need the resistor to be calcualted for various diode voltages(0.3 to 0.4).0.2V over the resistor.

Comment: You can take the datasheet for some standard diode like 1n4148 and use it as a reference.

Comment: If the value of R1 hasn't been provided in the question then your answer will be a function of the value of R1. Given they have provided the voltage V1 I would have expected a value for R1 so you can provide an absolute answer for Vout.

Comment: @Batt Did they specify \$R_\text{S}=0\:\Omega\$? It may not be important, depending on \$R_1\$. You can solve this without iteration, or with.   Refer to the Shockley diode equation.

Comment: @mhaselup They have given a value for R1 which is 2k.

Comment: If R1 is 2k, the current will be 0.5mA or less. The voltage drop over the diodes will be a non linear function of the current. Check the dataset for a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an idea of the iterative method let's assume a value of 4K ohms for R1

1. And let's make an initial guess of 0.3V across each diode totalling 0.6V
2. Given 1V - 0.6V = 0.4V drop across 4K ohms will provide a current of 0.1mA check using the Diode model the corresponding forward voltage (x2 for two diodes) and get a new estimate for the voltage across them.
3. Plug the model calculated forward voltage into your original equation and recalculate the current i.e. (1V - 2*Vd)/4K and repeat step 2.

Stop when Vout changes between steps by <=15mV

Comment: I can't quite get the last statement. For ex, if for the first iteration to 6th iteration, i get a diff of +-1mV, and then for thet next, I get 15mV difference from the last iteration, I should stop?

Comment: You will get a series of values for Vout e.g. 0.6, 0.5, 0.45, 0.435, .. for example. Since the last two values differ by 0.15 (15 mV) you can stop at this point.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: Is it right that I should be using 2*Vd when using the exponential model formula for Id?

Comment: Work out the voltage Vd for the given current using the model. Then double it as you have two (presumably identical) diodes.

Comment: No Id is given. So Vd and Id are unknown quantities. So i thought we should at least guess either one for our initial assumption then use that value to find the other missing.

Comment: I=(1 - 2*Vd)/2000

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you're asked to find the output voltage within a tolerance of 15mV.
2. See above.
3. Initial assumption doesn't matter too much, it saves iterations if you are closer. If you assume a current (it will be fairly low in this case, maybe uA for a silicon diode), then calculate Vo, then you'll have a new current based on (1V-Vo)/R1. Calculate Vo again, repeat until it converges well enough.